# ListView update on insert, edit, delete notifyDataSetChanged() not working

Tags: android

I have a ListView bound to a SimpleCursorAdapter, and I want it to refresh when I modify the database (by inserting, updating or deleting rows). *cursor.notifyDataSetChanged()* has no effect (it's called on the UI thread) and *ListView.removeViewAt(int)* throws an *UnsupportedOperationException*.
What am I supposed to do on Android to get such a basic behavior?

Note that the database is correctly affected and the modification is shown when I restart the activity. But restarting the activity is not an option here, and changing the ListView adapter is the last resource here, since it's a hack and can't guarantee a smooth transition

**DISCLAIMER**
Quite basic question, asked millions of times and answered zero.
Please, **do not answer** if you have never done this in your code, don't ask for mine, and don't bother with *try this* or *try that*. **Only answer if you know how it's done**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From API >= 11 the way to do this is using a `CursorLoader`, this is also included in the Android Compatibility Library, so you can also use this if you are targeting a previous Android version. `CursorLoader` will make the query in a background thread and return you the cursor. **You will need to implement a `ContentProvider`**. You can read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html) to get an idea of how to use it. Basically you init a loader and then you restart it when you know data has changed. In the callback you just swap the cursor of your adapter.

Or you can just use `requery()` on the `Cursor`. The adapter will get automatically notified of the changes. This method is deprecated now and, of course, it's not the recommended way.